# angular way to focus into next input

Tags: angularjs

I need to validate a few input characters as required and when all of them are entered, I would be making an ajax call to verify if the combination of them is correct or not on the server.

The problem I am stuck with it is, I need to move the focus to next input as soon as the user is done typing in the character.

I can easily do this with jQuery or Javascript, but I need to do it using AngularJs, in a proper "Angular Way".

Stuff I have tried so far is as below.

My HTML

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myController", ["$scope", function myController($scope) {
  $scope.verify = function verify() {
    //here I would have my code to verify the combination of characters entered by the user
  };
}]);

myApp.directive("moveToNext", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: ['ngModel'],
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
            element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
                if (element[0].value.trim().length > 0) {

                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```css
.code-character {
    width:25px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: solid lightgrey 2px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input type="text" class="code-character" maxlength="1" ng-model="firstCharacter" name="firstCharacter" required autofocus move-to-next="verify()" />
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" class="code-character" maxlength="1" ng-model="secondCharacter" name="secondCharacter" required autofocus move-to-next="verify()" />
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" class="code-character" maxlength="1" ng-model="thirdCharacter" name="thirdCharacter" required autofocus move-to-next="verify()" />
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" class="code-character" maxlength="1" ng-model="fourthCharacter" name="fourthCharacter" required autofocus move-to-next="verify()" />
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" class="code-character" maxlength="1" ng-model="fifthCharacter" name="fifthCharacter" required autofocus move-to-next="verify()" />
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" class="code-character" maxlength="1" ng-model="sixthCharacter" name="sixthCharacter" required autofocus move-to-next="verify()" />
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

How do I find and focus on the next element once it has got some value?

Comment: make a plunker so that others can do it faster

Answer (score 1):

you can find next empty input with jquery

```
element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
  if (element[0].value.trim().length > 0) {
      $(element).closest('tr').find('input').each(function(){
          if($(this).val().length === 0){
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
          }
      })
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! With jQuery it can be done for sure. However, I am interested in knowing if there is any better way of doing the same with Angular. You know, the "Angular Way", as they say! :) I will wait for some time if I get a response in that direction. Otherwise, I will use your solution. Thank you again!